How To Use IF Statement and Local Variables In Stored Procedures
I'm testing this in MyPhpAdmin on "10.5.24-MariaDB-cll-lve",  I can not define SET statements such as "SET @x = 1;" (from the manual),they don't fail but the following statementis flagged as failing.  I have also tried DECLARE.
If I put a begin/end around the procedure then it will save but fail to execute telling me that it fails with "... near NULL at line 1".
The following shows a simple cut down test case of trying to declare variables (a delimiter issue of some type?):
#BEGIN
#   DELIMITER $$
#    $$
    #SET @try1 = 1$$
    #SET @try1 = 1, @try2 = 2, @try3 = 3$$
    #SET @try4 = 4, @try5 = 5, @try6 = 6$$ (failed on start of this line)
    
    
    SET @try1 = 1;
    SET @try2 = 2;
    SET @try3 = 3;
    
#   DELIMITER ;
#END


If I use the SQL to create the stored proc shown here, it works, if I add another declare/set like the following it fails to create complaining about my second set!:
   DECLARE total_value INT;
       SET total_value = 50;
       
   DECLARE total_value2 INT;
       SET total_value2 = 50;

The following shows what I'm actually trying to do:
I am using dynamic SQL here as IF statements with static were also failing.
I have exported that and added it here:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`wcipporg`@`localhost`
    PROCEDURE `BBBBBBBBB`
        (IN `SinceDate` DATE,
         IN `Totals` VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN

DECLARE selectP1 VARCHAR(999);
    SET selectP1 = 'SELECT SinceDate AS `Sales Since`,';
    
IF Totals = 'N' THEN 
   SET @selectP2 = 'wp_posts.post_title AS Plant,
                    wp_terms.name AS Container,';
ELSE    
   SET @selectP2 = "COALESCE(wp_posts.post_title, '### All Plants ###')      AS `Plant Name`,
                    COALESCE(wp_terms.name,       '### All Containers ###')  AS `Container`,";
END IF;        
SET @selectP3 = 'SUM(sold_plants.how_many) AS Total
                 FROM wcipporg_Bungalook.sale AS sale
                 INNER JOIN wcipporg_Bungalook.sold_plants AS sold_plants
                         ON sale.txn_id = sold_plants.txn_id
                 INNER JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_posts AS wp_posts
                         ON sold_plants.plant_id = wp_posts.ID
                 INNER JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_terms AS wp_terms
                         ON sold_plants.container_id = wp_terms.term_id
                 WHERE sale.txn_time >= SinceDate';
IF Totals = 'N' THEN 
   SET @selectP3 = 'GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name';
ELSE    
   SET @selectP3 = 'GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name WITH ROLLUP';
END IF;


SET @query = CONCAT(@selectP1, @selectP2, @selectP3, @selectP4);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

I've tried all sorts of variations, googling and the manual, the error messages say the manual for my version but it doesn't say how to find that specific manual, I am using: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/documentation/

Looks like sticking to procedure variables and avoiding user variable in procedures would be good. Also  see execute immediate.

@danblack, I wanted to use stored procedures as that is apparently much better from a security perspective.  The Execute immediate looks useful, thanks.

Some things I now believe to be true for mariadb stored procedures:

Best to use BEGIN/END to enclose stored procedure (whether required or not).
@variables do work. I thought, converting passed IN parameters to @variables would make testing outside of the procedure much easier (but IF not supported).
"DECLARE" STATEMENTS, if used, must all appear first (can't interleave with associated "SET" statements).
Error 1064 Near NULL at line 1 occurs if a variable hasn't been intialised, a mistake meant that "selectP4" wasn't being set.

Here is my final working code
BEGIN
SET @InStoredProc = 'Y';
    IF  @InStoredProc = 'N' THEN 
        SET @SinceDate = '2020-01-01';
        SET @Totals    = 'Y';
    ELSE
        SET @SinceDate = SinceDate;
        SET @Totals    = Totals;
    END IF;

SET @AllPlants     = '### All Plants ###';
SET @AllContainers = '### All Containers ###';

SET @SelectP1 = CONCAT('SELECT "', @SinceDate, '" AS `@Sales Since`,');

IF @Totals = 'N' THEN 
   SET @SelectP2 = 'wp_posts.post_title AS Plant,
                    wp_terms.name AS Container,';
ELSE    
   SET @SelectP2 = "COALESCE(wp_posts.post_title, @AllPlants)      AS `Plant Name`,
                    COALESCE(wp_terms.name,       @AllContainers)  AS `Container`,";
END IF;        

SET @SelectP3 = 'SUM(sold_plants.how_many) AS Total
                FROM wcipporg_Bungalook.sale AS sale
                INNER JOIN wcipporg_Bungalook.sold_plants AS sold_plants
                        ON sale.txn_id = sold_plants.txn_id
                INNER JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_posts AS wp_posts
                        ON sold_plants.plant_id = wp_posts.ID
                INNER JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_terms AS wp_terms
                        ON sold_plants.container_id = wp_terms.term_id
                WHERE sale.txn_time >= "';
SET @SelectP3 = CONCAT(@SelectP3, @SinceDate, '"');

IF @Totals = 'N' THEN 
   SET @SelectP4 = ' GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name';
ELSE    
   SET @SelectP4 = ' GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name WITH ROLLUP';
END IF;


SET @Query = CONCAT(@SelectP1, @SelectP2, @SelectP3, @SelectP4);
#SET OUTPUT = @Query;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END


re 1, seems like you just need to fix your expectation of when BEGIN/END is needed.  if the body of the procedure is not just a single simple statement (e.g. INSERT/SELECT), you need a compound statement with BEGIN/END.  and SET or DECLARE count as additional statements, requiring BEGIN/END

re 4, yes, any expression including a NULL argument or operand usually produces a NULL value.  so if you do CONCAT('SELECT "', @SinceDate, '" AS @Sales Since,') and @SinceDate is unset, the CONCAT result will be NULL.

this looks very wrong, but I don't know what you intended: '" AS `@Sales Since...

@ysth, When I export it it adds begin/end, when I add them and export it drops them from the exported data, implying that they are not required.  They are as we have said.  The error message says NULL on line 1 (no matter where the error is, unless this is because it was dynamic sql, I thought I had the same in static, not sure...)..  The '@' starts the colname..  There is not much in the way of SQL examples that are are meaningfully complex to demonstrate common issues, any docs I have found is cryptic for non SQL experts, this is why I added the summary for others.

what are you using to export?  it should not be dropping required begin/ends

@ysth, I'm using PhpMyAdmin to export.  I just tried it again on a small script and I can't reproduce that behaviour, I was probably wrong as I was trying all sorts of variations.

DECLARE selectP1 VARCHAR(999);
    SET selectP1 = 'SELECT SinceDate AS `Sales Since`,';

-->
    SET @selectP1 = 'SELECT SinceDate AS `Sales Since`,';

That is, use @variables, not declared variables.
(Tip:  Change arguments and declared variables to have a leading _ to distinguish from column names, etc:  _Total, etc.)

Thanks for the reply, but as mentioned I have also tried @variables (although "declare" should also work according to the manual and examples I've seen).  There must be something fundamentally wrong with what I am doing.  I can't even use '@variables' / declare without the begin/end allowing me to save the queries.  Ah, OK, I see the forgotten declare, I fixed up the SET as well, same diff (NULL line 1).

I just want to clarify the need for BEGIN/END and explain that I have learnt most of what I know of  SQL in the last couple of weeks. and that I've had no problems creating and executing stored procedures WITHOUT variables.  I'm using MyPhpAdmin to create the "routines" and so I only need to type the body of the procedure, the begin end statements I mention have been required within this procedure body and disappear in the exported value I used in the OP.

@DennisBareis - @x is not the same as DECLARE x.

@DennisBareis - If you are just now learning SQL, I recommend avoiding Stored Routines; they have many confusing and messy rules.

AT RICK (can't get @ to work)
I never said they were the same, for my purposes, having variables, both worked.

@DennisBareis - There are 2 things going on -- (1) The difference between @variables and DECLARED variable, and (2) DELIMITER is used to bracket the declaration of a stored routine, not for terminating simple statements.

Actually, I think the problem was that the stored procedure contents is not treated as a block so it needs begin & end statements at least in the MyPhpAdmin iinterface, these "extra" begin,end disappear when SP exported. But remain in the interface when re-editing... The very poor SQL error message about null on line 1 initially put me off this solution

In your phpMyAdmin example, you are missing BEGIN and END around the procedure code. That is why the second SET is failing. Also, DECLARE statements need to be at the beginning of the procedure, just after the BEGIN.
Try to avoid dynamic SQL in stored procedures. Dynamic SQL makes the code more error-prone and harder to maintain. Since you are essentially generating two different queries, it might be better to use two separate procedures. If you want to use just one procedure, you can use the following code:
CREATE DEFINER=`wcipporg`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BBBBBBBBB` (
in_SinceDate DATE,
in_Totals VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN

IF (in_Totals = 'N') THEN 
  SELECT 
    in_SinceDate AS `Sales Since`,
    wp_posts.post_title AS Plant,
    wp_terms.name AS Container,
    SUM(sold_plants.how_many) AS Total
  FROM wcipporg_Bungalook.sale AS sale
    JOIN wcipporg_Bungalook.sold_plants AS sold_plants ON sale.txn_id = sold_plants.txn_id
    JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_posts AS wp_posts ON sold_plants.plant_id = wp_posts.ID
    JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_terms AS wp_terms ON sold_plants.container_id = wp_terms.term_id
  WHERE sale.txn_time >= in_SinceDate
  GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name;
ELSE 
  SELECT 
    in_SinceDate AS `Sales Since`,
    COALESCE(wp_posts.post_title, '### All Plants ###')      AS `Plant Name`,
    COALESCE(wp_terms.name,       '### All Containers ###')  AS `Container`,
    SUM(sold_plants.how_many) AS Total
  FROM wcipporg_Bungalook.sale AS sale
    JOIN wcipporg_Bungalook.sold_plants AS sold_plants ON sale.txn_id = sold_plants.txn_id
    JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_posts AS wp_posts ON sold_plants.plant_id = wp_posts.ID
    JOIN wcipporg_wp596.wpi2_terms AS wp_terms ON sold_plants.container_id = wp_terms.term_id
  WHERE sale.txn_time >= in_SinceDate
  GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title ASC, wp_terms.name WITH ROLLUP;
END IF;

END


there are pros/cons for both ways but have decided to use static SQL as suggested as it is easier to test within the SQL limitations that exist. AT:slaakso I don't know why for some people '@' names don't work (they get removed on save and no popup suggestions)!

@DennisBareis Do now know what you are referring to when you say some people '@' names don't work or what save/popup are you referring to.

In stackoverflow, I can't refer to you AT:slaakso @slaakso When it works a tooltip shows the user name as I type the userid.  UPDATE: Might have worked this time as the text didn't just get stripped out as usual...
